# Android - Intent Acitivity to a Fragment of a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` and want to get to 1 of the `Fragment` of a `FragmentActivity`

im trying

```
startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, (MainActivity)SecondFragment.class));
```

It is because you can't call `Fragments` via Intent? iknow that `Fragment` is a part of an `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: you cant do it that way send a bundle to MainActivity and on receiving the bundle direct to the SecondFragment

Comment: What do you mean you want to get to the fragment of another Activity? You can simply start the Activity with an Intent containing an extra telling the called activity what fragment to show if this needs to be determined at runtime

Comment: thanks @IllegalArgument I will try that.

nyarlathotep77, the intent is to have an activity to move to a fragment of an fragmentactivity.

Comment: No. From activity you can't call fragment directly. You need to call using FragmentTransaction or need to call FragmentActivity.

Comment: Yes, thank you guys. I think FragmentTransaction is something that I am looking for.just need to learn how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try below code to change fragment inside activity.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment(),
                        "" + _HomeFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

From a Fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), mFragmentFavorite.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

From an Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, mFragmentFavorite.class);
startActivity(intent);
```